# Height of angular-material table not going below certain minimum height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-table in my project and would like to set the height of the rows to something like 20-30px.

When I set `height: 25px` what I get is actual height of 47.8px and if I set the `height` to something greater than 47.8px the row height increases, which means it's not a problem with css selectors and specificity.

I'm using the directive like so:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [ngClass]="classes"></table>
```

In my css I have:

```css
.mat-cell, .mat-header-cell {
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

I have checked and there doesn't appear to be a `min-height` attribute set anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```css
.mat-row {
  height: 25px;
}
```

Here you can see a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57366849?file=app/table-basic-example.css).